# That's "great idea" or "a great idea"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, spoken-english

I think I've heard both of the following two sentences:

> That's *a great* idea.
>
> That's *great* idea.

Are they both correct? Do they have any differences?

Comment: You _can_ say "That's great", though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct.

Usually in English, if you have a singular noun, you need an article, either "a" or "the", or a possessive (like "Bob's great idea") or the word "one".

Comment: That's a good answer.

Comment: But not, "That's good answer." :-)